# Using ember-cp-validations across multi-page form

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

I have an `order` model that I’m collecting data for over a multi-page form. I’ve created some validations like this:

```
const Validations = buildValidations({
  // these should only be used when we’re on checkout.info route
  name: validator('presence', true),
  email: [
    validator('presence', true),
    validator('format', { type: 'email' })
  ],
  // these should only be used when we’re on checkout.shipping route
  address1: validator('presence', true),
  address2: validator('presence', true),
  city: validator('presence', true),
});
```

My model is set up to use them like this:

```
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  // model set-up in here
})
```

What I’d like to happen is for it to only validate `name` and `email` when I’m on `checkout.info` and to validate `address1`, `address2` and `city` when I’m on `checkout.shipping`.

One of the things I’ve tried already is running the validations inside of my `checkout-form` component:

```
let { m, validations } = order.validateSync({
  on: ['name', 'email']
})
const isValid = validations.get('isValid')
order.set('didValidate', isValid)
```

The problem is that this doesn’t seem to unblock the disabled state on my form’s next button

```
{{next-button disabled=(v-get model.order 'isInvalid')}}
```

Another thing I tried was to build a custom `routed-presence` validator that disables `presence` when it’s not on the current route. The trouble with this is that other validators will still block this (e.g. type or length).

How might I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not well documented, you can enable or disable validations based on a condition that your model computes:

```
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

export default Ember.Object.extend(buildValidations({

  email: {
    disabled: Ember.computed.alias('model.isCheckoutPage'),
    validators: [
      ...
    ],
  }
}), {
  // could be a computed property too
  isCheckoutPage: false,
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks! How would I go about passing the current route information into my model? For example being able to check something like `computed.equal('model.currentPath', 'checkout.shipping')`?

Comment: I’ve gone with adding `step: attr('string')` to my `order` model. In my `checkout-form` component I’m doing `this.get('model.order').setProperties({ step: this.get('router.currentPath') })`, and then `disabled: !computed.equal('model.step', 'checkout.shipping')` inside of my validations. It doesn’t seem to work though… anything I’ve done that’s obviously wrong?

Comment: Believe you'll need to use a second computed property `disabled: computed.not()` or a custom computed property, I don't think you can negate like you are doing ...